PWM Switch models by C. Basso for LTSpice/QSpice
I am reading "SMPS SPICE simulations and practical design" by C. Basso, and I want to follow along with my own simulations. Are there any models of the PWM switches available for LTSpice or QSpice?

You need to quote some portions of that book, and explain in more detail what you want. You can't expect this community to purchase some random book in order to understand what you're asking. Unless it is a very widely used book that every other EE owns.

@Velvet I mean... you sort of can.  Chris hangs out here, as it happens.  There's no way to "at" someone until they've participated in a question, though, and it's up to chance whether someone sees something addressed to them. So it's a bit of a long shot.

@TimWilliams On his website (that you've linked), he encourages dropping him an email.

A simple search on relevant keywords finds the author's website: https://powersimtof.com/Spice.htm
Scrolling down towards the bottom, the "New models to download" section seems to be of interest.  I don't know if these models are specifically what's referred to/used in the book.
